# awk printing lines with criteria - greater than

Tags: awk

```
cat file.txt |  awk  ' /queryId/; /stats_missing/; /memory/'
```

Command above produces below results:

```
queryId : 3440b6c90a6ccec1
  stats_missing : true
  memory : 500
queryId : d94bf4e4756e6342
  stats_missing : false
  memory : 200
```

What I want is to produce only results where memory > certain number (ex 300)
So my output would only produce memory : (number greater than 300)

```
queryId : d94bf4e4756e6342
  stats_missing : false
  memory : 500
```

Sample source data from file.txt

```
queryId : 794d12600c5b11ad:c79abeee00000000
statement : SELECT `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`filedt` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`ssn` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`suff` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`ln_num` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`prog` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`dlqdys` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`status` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`currprin` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`origprin` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`rpmtbegdt` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`forbmos` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`owner` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`frstdsbdt` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`uniq_loan_id` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`.`fdr_acct_nbr` FROM `edw_sandbox`.`e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118` `e88172_FIRSTFORBS_103118`  LIMIT 10000
queryType : QUERY
queryState : FINISHED
startTime : 2018-12-19T22:29:02.235Z
rowsProduced : null
attributes : {
  thread_cpu_time_percentage : 51
  thread_network_receive_wait_time : 34
  thread_cpu_time : 166
  hdfs_average_scan_range : 3.3535640666666668E7
  bytes_streamed : 3572722
  hdfs_bytes_read : 100606922
  query_status : OK
  hdfs_scanner_average_bytes_read_per_second : 1.358740106189443E9
  thread_network_receive_wait_time_percentage : 11
  oom : false
  planning_wait_time_percentage : 0
  admission_wait : 0
  connected_user : e88172
  stats_missing : false
  planning_wait_time : 9
  client_fetch_wait_time_percentage : 0
  session_type : HIVESERVER2
  memory : 629145600
  client_fetch_wait_time : 6
  file_formats :
  admission_result : Admitted immediately
  pool : root.default
  session_id : e3463e2b18af960e:56a
  stats_corrupt : false
  thread_total_time : 329
  thread_network_send_wait_time_percentage : 5
  impala_version : impalad version 2.10.0-cdh5.13.3 RELEASE (build 15a453e15865344e75ce0fc6c4c760696d50f626)
  network_address : 172.19.79.81:44886
  thread_storage_wait_time_percentage : 34
  thread_network_send_wait_time : 15
  thread_storage_wait_time : 112
```

Comment: @oguzismail provided example. Please upvote if it satisfies you

Comment: If you post the sample source data, perhaps better answers will come up.  Most likely you already have a record structure in the source.

Comment: @karakfa thanks, I posted the sample source data

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to do this depending on the structure of your input data.

Assuming the `stats_missing` and `memory` lines will always be present following the `queryId`, you could do something like:

```
awk -F':' '/queryId/ {query=$0}
     /stats_missing/ {stats=$0}
     /memory/ {mem=$2}
     query && stats && mem>5000 {
        print query;print stats; print "memory: "mem; query=stats=mem="";}'
```

This stores the lines matching `query`, `stats_missing`, and the value of `memory`, then when all 3 are populated AND the `memory` value is over 5000 (in this example), it prints them out.

E.g.

```
$ cat mem.txt
queryId : 3440b6c90a6ccec1
  stats_missing : true
  memory : 493719877394422178
queryId : d94bf4e4756e6342
  stats_missing : false
  memory : 2214592512
queryId : 3440b6c90a6ccec1
  stats_missing : true
  memory : 4978
queryId : d94bf4e4756e6342
  stats_missing : false
  memory : 200


$ awk -F':' '/queryId/ {query=$2}
     /stats_missing/ {stats=$2}
     /memory/ {mem=$2}
     query && stats && mem>5000 {
        print "queryId:"query;print "stats_missing:"stats; print "memory:"mem; query=stats=mem="";}' mem.txt
queryId: 3440b6c90a6ccec1
stats_missing: true
memory: 493719877394422178
queryId: d94bf4e4756e6342
stats_missing: false
memory: 2214592512
```

As mentioned though, this can get all out of whack if those other two lines aren't always present before the next query ID.

If that is not the case, you'd have to do something like keep track of each time you encounter a new queryId and reset the variables then. Or do something like store all the queryId,stats_missing,and memory data in an array based on the last queryId encountered, then print everything at the end. Many ways to skin this cat, depending.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is easy with `Perl` with a multiline [regex](https://regex101.com/r/sF9ao2/1):

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE 'while (/^(queryId[\s\S]+?^\h*memory\h*:\h*)(\d+)/mg){ say "$1$2" if $2<300}' file
queryId : d94bf4e4756e6342
    stats_missing : false
    memory : 200

$ perl -0777 -lnE 'while (/^(queryId[\s\S]+?^\h*memory\h*:\h*)(\d+)/mg){ say "$1$2" if $2>300}' file
queryId : 3440b6c90a6ccec1
    stats_missing : true
    memory : 500
```